# Factory method to return an implementation of a given Interface

Tags: java, generics

Consider the code:

```
/**
 * For a given interface, return a default implementation
 */
public class ImplementationFactory<T>
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    AddressBookUI ui = ImplementationFactory.getImpl(AddressBookUI.class);
  }

  public static <T extends BasicUI> T getImpl(Class<T> uiClass)
  {
    if (uiClass.equals(AddressBookUI.class))
    {
      /*
       * Compile error if cast is removed.
       * Casting to T leaves an unchecked cast warning.
       */
      return (T) new AddressBookFrame();
    }

    // a bunch more else-if checks would be here

    return null;
  }
}

// These are defined elsewhere:
interface BasicUI {}
interface AddressBookUI extends BasicUI {}
interface StockQuoteUI extends BasicUI {}

class AddressBookFrame implements AddressBookUI {}
class StockQuoteFrame implements StockQuoteUI {}
```

Why is the cast in getImpl() even needed in the first place?  Is there a better way to go about this?

Also, instead of chained if-else checks in getImpl(), I tried creating a Map as:

```
private static Map<Class<? extends BasicUI>, Class<? extends BasicUI>> map;
```

I would then call newInstance() on the value from the map, but the problems were:

- Still had to cast
- No type safety if I put the wrong implementation into the map.

Ideally, the map would be

- key = some BasicUI interface
- value = some class implementation of that key

but I didn't know how to do it.

**EDIT:** added another implementation of BasicUI to the code

Answer (score 1):

The cast is needed because, at compile time, there is no way to tell that an `AddressBookFrame` is an instance of `T`.

To avoid warnings, check the type at runtime:

```
return uiClass.cast(new AddressBookFrame());
```

Doing it this way, your map implementation would work and would be type-safe.

Comment: "because, at compile time, there is no way to tell..."  I guess that's the crux of my confusion.  What can't it?  For a given supplied type (AddressBookUI) it should know if the return class (AddressBookFrame) is of that type, which it is.

Comment: You know that, as the programmer, because you did the `.equals()` check. The compiler isn't that smart.

Comment: The .equals() check was on the given parameter (basically a long-form substitute for a Map). The cast in question is on the returned instance.

Comment: "Doing it this way, your map implementation would work and would be type-safe". Perhaps I was unclear in my OP, but no.  See the edit I made to add another type and implementation of BasicUI.  I don't want to be able to say "map.put(AddressBookUI.class, StockQuoteFrame.class);" (mismatch)

Comment: OK, then just add a check after you create the map that throws an exception if any of the mappings are bad.